# URL expire implementation in SF

Tags: survey

I am using Survey Force to send survey email to customer. The survey email contains a link which call a VF page from surveyforce app. I want that the customer should be able to fill the survey form only once the link should expire once the user fills the survey

Comment: Are you saying you would like the link to be invalid once a certain date has passed?

Comment: Is it a anonymous survey or are you capturing any kind of unique ID through email?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom checkbox field in the Survey Object and when the user first click the Survey link in email check if the field is marked or not. If the field is marked then don't enable the Survey form.